# spring batch read from multiple files and write to one file

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have spring batch configuration which reads from multiple files and write mutiple file. Is it possible to write to only one file reading from multiple. Lets say i receive huge XML file, i split XML into small files and use partitioner and read small files parallel. But i need to write all the data read from different small xml files to one output file. Is this possible with spring batch?I know it is possible by making writer synchronized, but i am looking for any other possible way
Job configuration

```
@Bean
    public Job job(final Step parser) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("JOB")
                .flow(parser)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step parser(final Step parserWorker, final Partitioner partitioner) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("parser")
                .partitioner("parser", partitioner)
                .step(parserWorker)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step parserWorker(
            final StaxEventItemReader reader,
            final FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("parserWorker")
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(Integer.parseInt(chunkSize))
                .reader(reader)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public StaxEventItemReader<Employee> reader(final @Value("file:#{stepExecutionContext[file]}") Resource resource) {
        StaxEventItemReader<Employee> staxEventItemReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        staxEventItemReader.setResource(resource);
        staxEventItemReader.setFragmentRootElementName("Employee");
        Jaxb2Marshaller unMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        unMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Employee.class);
        staxEventItemReader.setUnmarshaller(unMarshaller);
        return staxEventItemReader;
    }

    @Bean()
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> fileWriter() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> fileWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        fileWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("out.csv"));
        EmployeeAggregator lineAggregator = new EmployeeAggregator();
        fileWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
        fileWriter.setLineSeparator(EMPTY_STRING);
        fileWriter.setHeaderCallback(new HeaderCallback());
        fileWriter.setFooterCallback(new FooterCallback());
        return innlesFileWriter;
    }
```

I get error `org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Output file was not created:`

Comment: when you are passing `out.csv` so is it already there? and you can have a look  `https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/flatfileitemwriter-write-to-csv-file/#demo`

Comment: generating multiple file and merging them will not work for me because of footer

Comment: Which footer? This is not mentioned in your description and there is no FooterCallback in your config. Please add all details in your question to be able to give you a correct answer in an efficient way.

Comment: i have updated question now

Comment: If the footer is what blocking from going parallel, I would append it to the final file in a separate step. Otherwise, use a staging area as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I am not very sure if writer footer in a seperate step will perform well. Consider file generated is 4Giga bytes. opening such big file and appending at end is difficult in my opinion

Comment: No,  "echo myfooter >> myBigFile.txt" is very efficient no matter how big the file is. Doing the same in Java by opening a file in append mode is equally efficient. Give it a try to be sure. At least, with this approach, you can process all your partitions in parallel without concurrency issues, which will boost the performance of your overall job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have spring batch configuration which reads from multiple files and write mutiple file.

You can create an additional step that merges the output files. Since the output file is a flat file, this can be done without any issue (that would be a bit more problematic if the output file was an XML file since you need to deal with XML declaration, headers, etc when merging files).

Another technique is to use a staging area (a table, a queue, etc) and add a step that reads from the staging area and write to the final file.